# Oracle selecting CHAR datatype

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate, jpa

For example I have a table (Oracle) `myTable` with a field `myField` which is a `CHAR` of length `5`.

If I try to query something like below directly in sql dev or some other tools

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myField = 'aa'
```

I get some results as expected (Notice that I am comparing `'aa'` to some db-padded values like `'aa   '`(padded with 3 trailing spaces to fit 5) etc.

**Problem:**
If I try to run such query using JPA Hibernate for example, I am not getting the same results (nothing even) **UNLESS** I either `TRIM` the CHAR field before comparing like

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE TRIM(myField) = 'aa'
```

OR

I pad my parameter (but this requires me to know the CHAR length beforehand) like

```
 FROM myTable WHERE TRIM(myField) = 'aa   '
```

**Questions:** Are the two above my only options? I'll gladly welcome more options aside from above. Which has the better performance? Thanks.

Comment: If you can change the schema, convert all CHAR columns to VARCHAR columns and live happily ever after.

Comment: This works as specified. Columns of type `CHAR` are always padded to the defined length. If you don't want that, don't use `CHAR`. See the manual for details: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#i45647

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: As far as I know, it doesn't work with Hibernate because Hibernate has its independent type information, uses prepared statements with bound parameters and declares them as Java strings. This type information is then carried over to SQL. As a consequence, Oracle's type conversion rules column promote the value to varchar2 and compare it as such; thus the comparison doesn't match.