# Oracle CHAR datatypes dont work with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, entity-framework

I have an issue returning data from on Oracle database using a WHERE clause which targets a CHAR column.

I have provided the steps below which should allow the issue to be recreated:

**Database Setup**

Run the following SQL to create the database table and insert mock data:

`CREATE TABLE ORDERS (ORDER_NUMBER CHAR(10 BYTE));`
`INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES ('123456');`
`SELECT REPLACE(ORDER_NUMBER, ' ', '#') as ORDER_NUMBER from ORDERS`

ORDER_NUMBER
 123456####

As you can see, the value stored in the table is padded out with spaces to 10 characters (replaced by '#' to make them apparent).

**Entity Framework Setup**

```
public class Order
{
    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
}

public class OrderMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Order>
{
    public OrderMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        HasKey(t => t.OrderNumber);

        Property(t => t.OrderNumber)
            .HasColumnName("ORDER_NUMBER")
            .IsRequired()
            .IsFixedLength()
            .HasMaxLength(10)
            .HasColumnType("CHAR")
            .IsUnicode(false);
    }
}

public class OrdersContext()
{
    static OrdersContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<OrderContext>(null);
    }

    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)  
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new OrderMap());
    }
}
```

**The Problem**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {           
        using (var context = new OrdersContext())
        {
            var order1 = context.Orders
                                .FirstOrDefault(o => o.OrderNumber == "123456");

            // This works, the record is found in the database and I did not have to pad the filter sting to 10 characters
            Debug.WriteLine("OrderNumber:" + order1.WorksOrder);

            var orderFilter = "123456";
            var order2 = context.Orders
                                .FirstOrDefault(o => o.WorksOrder == orderFilter);

            // This fails. Using a variable to specify the filter does not work. No record is found.
            Debug.WriteLine("OrderNumber:" + order2.WorksOrder);
        }
    }
}
```

So, the issue is that when I want to use a variable (`orderFilter`), the statement does not return a record.  I can make this work by padding `orderFilter` as follows, but I don't think I should have to do this:

```
var orderFilter = "123456".PadRight(10);
var order2 = context.Orders.FirstOrDefault(o => o.WorksOrder == orderFilter);

// This now works
Debug.WriteLine("OrderNumber:" + order2.WorksOrder);
```

It appears as through the SQL generated when using a bind variable does not set the correct datatype on the bind variable.  If I enable tracing, we see the following SQL:

> Opened connection at 22/04/2015 12:15:12 +01:00
>
> SELECT  "Extent1"."ORDER_NUMBER" AS "ORDER_NUMBER",  FROM "ORDERS"
>   "Extent1" WHERE ("Extent1"."ORDER_NUMBER" = :p__linq__0) AND (ROWNUM
>   <= (1) )
>
> -- p__linq__0: '123456    ' (Type = Object)
>
> -- Executing at 22/04/2015 12:15:12 +01:00
>   -- Completed in 13 ms with result: OracleDataReader

I have also tried using `DbFunctions.AsNonUnicode(orderFilter)` but this seems to have little effect.

Can anyone explain what is going on here?  How do I filter on CHAR datatypes without padding the filter or trimming the column data?

**NOTE**
I cannot change the data type of the column in the database.

This issue is logged in several places but with no definitive answer:

- [Oracle selecting CHAR datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578545/oracle-selecting-char-datatype)
- [ODP.NET / EF6 - CHAR datatype in WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28244561/odp-net-ef6-char-datatype-in-where-clause)
- https://community.oracle.com/thread/3654585

Version Numbers of all the things:

- Entity Framework 6.1.3
- .Net Framework 4.5.1
- Oracle.ManagedDataAccess 4.121.2.0 ODAC 12c Release 3
- Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework 6.121.2.0
- Oracle database is 11.2.0.3.0

Comment: I have not really worked with that data type much lately, but I used to and this was expected behavior (either trim or pad). I agree with @a_horse_with_no_name (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578545/oracle-selecting-char-datatype) that this is expected behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the response Patrick. If it is expected, why is it not consistent between a literal string and using a variable? `.FirstOrDefault(o => o.OrderNumber == "123456");` vs `.FirstOrDefault(o => o.OrderNumber == orderFilter);`

Comment: It would be nice if there were a means to apply `variable.PadRight(FixedLengthFieldMeta.Length)` globally within the context to any fixed length CHAR column rather than having to remember that each query needs to pad the parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can explain what is going on. The solution is to change the CHAR column (which I note you say you can't) otherwise be aware of the subtleties when comparing against it.

Tom Kyte's section on the CHAR datatype in his superb book "Expert Oracle Database Architecture" is the source for this answer. The following is based on the 2nd edition pages 499 - 502.

**Short answer**

Character literals get promoted whilst variable length bind variables do not.

**Explanation**

(All the following were run using SQLPlus against 12.1.0.2 Database (but nothing shown is unique to 12c)

Create and populate a table with CHAR and VARCHAR2 columns:

```
CREATE TABLE ORDERS (ORDER_NUMBER_CHAR       CHAR(10 BYTE),
                     ORDER_NUMBER_VARCHAR2   VARCHAR2(10 BYTE));

INSERT INTO ORDERS(ORDER_NUMBER_CHAR, 
                   ORDER_NUMBER_VARCHAR2)
VALUES ('123456',
        '123456');
```

In the first query which uses the VARCHAR2 column in the WHERE clause, it works as expected and a row is returned.

```
SELECT *
  FROM orders
 WHERE order_number_varchar2 = '123456';
```

In the next query the WHERE clause uses the CHAR column. This query returns a row which means an implicit conversion has taken place whereby the CHAR(6) literal gets promoted to a CHAR(10)

```
SELECT *
  FROM orders
 WHERE order_number_char = '123456';
```

The implicit promotion must have happened because the strings are of different
lengths which is shown by this query which returns no rows

```
SELECT *
  FROM orders
 WHERE order_number_char = order_number_varchar2;
```

The next example shows that the VARCHAR2 bind variable is not promoted in the same way as the character literal so this query returns no rows

```
variable vc2 VARCHAR2(10 BYTE);
exec :vc2 := '123456'; 

SELECT *
  FROM orders
 WHERE order_number_char = :vc2;
```

If the correct CHAR bind variable is used then the record will be found, the final query returns the row as expected.

```
variable the_char CHAR(10 BYTE);
exec :the_char := '123456'; 

SELECT *
  FROM orders
 WHERE order_number_char = :the_char;
```

You should also be aware that the application will be impacted if the CHAR column ever changes size, i.e. if it was increased to 20 then the PadRight method would need to be changed accordingly.

Finally I thought it was also worth quoting Tom's summing up of the CHAR datatype in full.

> It is for these reasons—the fixed-width storage, which tends to make
>   the tables and related indexes much larger than normal, coupled with
>   the bind variable issue—that I avoid the CHAR type in all
>   circumstances. I cannot even make an argument for it in the case of
>   the one-character field, because in that case it is really of no
>   material difference. The VARCHAR2(1) and CHAR(1) are identical in all
>   aspects. There is no compelling reason to use the CHAR type in that
>   case, and to avoid any confusion, I “just say no,” even for the
>   CHAR(1) field.

Comment: Thanks Ian. I agree that the CHAR datatype is aweful. Im stuck with the legacy database & our DBA seems to love CHARS :( The question I suppose then is how do I get Entity Framework to pass the correct bind variable type so that the promotion occurs? I would have assumed that the `EntityTypeConfiguration` has a mistake in it somewhere preventing the correct bind variable type being used.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Time to switch all my CHARs to VARCHARS.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is EF6 passing parameter as varchar2 type to oracle. 
1. using

> Install-Package EntityFramework.Functions -Version 1.4.1

to add a function `RightPad(string str, int length, string padChar)` map to Oracle RPAD function

2. set MaxLength of Entity properity
3. [add a GetColumnMaxLength function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081109/entity-framework-4-0-automatically-truncate-trim-string-before-insert)
4. write code like below, you can get you data and the database index is working

.

```
int length = GetColumnMaxLength(dbContext, "Vessel","VesselName");
dbContext.Set<Vessel>().Where(m=>m.VesselName.StartWith(RPad(vesselName, length,""))
```

using `StartWith` instead of = symbol. because when you extend the column length on db before publishing program, `StartWith` can make old program working well.but
you still need to change Entity properity's MaxLength and publish later

Answer (score 0):

Try to Compare with Trim() on the entity fields....

Comment: Had the same problem.

Comment: retval = DB.TBL_PRIVATE_CONTACTS.Where(A=> A.ContactInfo.Trim() == "HHH").ToList();
In this example ContactInfo is a CHAR(6) column in the oracle DB.